# Access Control Allow Origin in Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am getting a request from a JSP (from iPad) to a Servlet (my system). When I send the response to the JSP the browser and iPad app seem to discard the data coming from the proxy due to the missing header.
I set the header as

```
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
```

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is the header name coming from the iPad.
I have seen in the following link
            http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
that there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header type in Servlet.
Since the testing is going in different places, can you tell me the setheader I add is write one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do misinterpret the WikiPedia entry. In a servlet you are allowed to set whatever response header you want. The only constraint is that clients must be able to understand the header. Wikipedia does list the *official* HTTP headers available as per RFC 2616 and 4229 (see link you provided). Proprietary, custom headers are legal and often used.

In general you only have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when it comes to cross-domain script requests, e.g. the JSP retrieved from *domain1.com* does perform a client side request (JavaScript, AJAX) to a servlet hosted on *domain2.com*. Depending on your use case you have to decide whether you require the header or not. The official spec is available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). You should carefully read it... believe me!